# Having an error with creating a sqlite table in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm having a problem with creating a table:

**Error**:

> ```
> 08-31 02:31:21.559    4121-4121/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "limit": syntax error
> 08-31 02:31:21.689    4121-4121/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.mbb.common.SmsReceiver: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
> near "limit": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE
> feedback(type, speed, expaierdate, date , limit );
> ```

**MY Code**:

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE feedback(type , speed , expaierdate , date , limit);");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LIMIT is a [keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html).

You can either quote it:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE feedback(type, speed, expaierdate, date, \"limit\");");
```

(in which case you have to quote it every time you use it), or use another name:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE feedback(type, speed, expiredate, date, some_limit);");
```

Comment: +1 and a quick question, what is the data type of all these columns if you dont specify any? :)